# Livewire profile edit form content on the page does not change

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, profile

I edited the laravel livewire profile and updated the blade in the livewire resource and the content on the page does not change. How I can update content on page after changing code? I can remove all this code, but it's still remaining on page:

```
<x-jet-form-section submit="updateProfileInformation">
    <x-slot name="title">
        {{ __('Profile Information') }}
    </x-slot>

    <x-slot name="description">
        {{ __('Update your account\'s profile information and email address.') }}
    </x-slot>

    <x-slot name="form">
        <!-- Profile Photo -->
        @if (Laravel\Jetstream\Jetstream::managesProfilePhotos())
            <div x-data="{photoName: null, photoPreview: null}" class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-4">
                <!-- Profile Photo File Input -->
                <input type="file" class="hidden"
                            wire:model="photo"
                            x-ref="photo"
                            x-on:change="
                                    photoName = $refs.photo.files[0].name;
                                    const reader = new FileReader();
                                    reader.onload = (e) => {
                                        photoPreview = e.target.result;
                                    };
                                    reader.readAsDataURL($refs.photo.files[0]);
                            " />

                <x-jet-label for="photo" value="{{ __('Photo') }}" />

                <!-- Current Profile Photo -->
                <div class="mt-2" x-show="! photoPreview">
                    <img src="{{ $this->user->profile_photo_url }}" alt="{{ $this->user->name }}" class="rounded-full h-20 w-20 object-cover">
                </div>

        <!-- Name -->
        <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-4">
            <x-jet-label for="name" value="{{ __('Name') }}" />
            <x-jet-input id="name" type="text" class="mt-1 block w-full" wire:model.defer="state.name" autocomplete="name" />
            <x-jet-input-error for="name" class="mt-2" />
        </div>

    
</x-jet-form-section>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You need to provide more detail about the problem(s) you're encountering such as code examples, errors etc. Without this we can't help you. Despite what people think, most programmers are not mind readers.[:

Comment: I edited \vendor\laravel\jetstream\stubs\livewire\resources\views\profile\update-profile-information-form.blade.php file and after changes on page content does not change.

Comment: Can you please provide the code in your question.

Comment: I can remove all code from this file and on page it's remaining.

Comment: All code is /js/app.js, how after update \vendor\laravel\jetstream\stubs\livewire\resources\views\profile\update-profile-information-form.blade.php file rebuild /js/app.js?

Comment: It's **npm run prod** command, to update app.js.